# How do you address out-of-range values for datetime conversion from nvarchar?

Tags: sql, osisoft

I've just had a view set up for querying analytical data. Here is the code:

```
SELECT [Log Date] AS PI_TIMESTAMP, [Plant Area] + [Product] + [Process(Mfg)] + [Sample Point] + 
[Test Name] + '_RESULT' AS ALIAS, [Result_Clean] AS PI_VALUE, 0 AS PI_STATUS
FROM dbo.vw_STARLIMS_PI
WHERE [Log Date] > ? AND 
([Sample Status] = 'Done' OR
[Sample Status] = 'OOS' OR
[Sample Status] = 'Released' OR
[Sample Status] = 'Upload')
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

I'm getting the following error.

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Here is the [Log Date] format. The SQL database is using mdy.

`2021-12-30 12:10:00.000`

Any idea on what to try first? I would assume there are some incorrect Log Date entries that won't convert to this datetime format, but I'm not sure how to address the issue in that case. I am not sure what other possibilities there are to cause this error. I am fairly green in this field.

EDIT:
Here is an excerpt from the view's code relating to log time formatting:

```
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), LOGDATE, 101) + ' ' + LOGTIM AS DATETIME ) AS [Log Date]
```

The ? in the query are placeholders for the last scan time (LST). Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.osisoft.com/bundle/pi-interface-for-relational-database-rdbms-via-odbc/page/placeholders-for-replaceable-parameters.html), it appears to be SQL_Timestamp data type.

[Data Types in dbo.vw_STARLIMS_PI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mdFW.png)

[Data Types of LOGTIM and LOGDATE that make up Log Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPwZP.png)

It appears the time portion of the Log Date is converted from nvarchar when the view is created. LOGTIM appears to be the cause of the error.

Comment: Presumably you're storing your dates as a string? And presumably `vw_STARLIMS_PI` is a view - so this is the code you need to present.

Comment: Are you using Sql Server as the database (the error message format looks like it). What is the [Log Date] data type? How did you define the parameters indicated by  question marks (?): date or nvarchar?.  If [Log Date] is nvarchar, and ? is DATE, you can use TRY_CAST or TRY_CONVERT to convert [Log Date] without error (the invalid ones will become NULL). Also your WHERE condition does not make sense without parenthesis (if any **Log Date is > ?** holds no other condition is looked at).

Comment: I've just added more information. It appears the view is set up with Log Date as DATETIME.

Comment: @userMT, I am using SQL server as the database. The Log Date datatype appears to be datetime (see edit). I've also provided some info about the question marks. Maybe I can try to convert Log Date to Timestamp from Datetime. I'll fix that where condition that you're referencing, fairly new to this game.

Comment: there seem to be at least two locations where a conversion is attempted (conversion from string to datetime and fails): inside the view and on the WHERE clause comparisons. But [Plant Area] + [Product] + [Process(Mfg)] + [Sample Point] + 
[Test Name] is also a possibility. Is there a date/time column among those? what are the data types?
I suggest that you perform all conversions explicitly using TRY_CAST (or TRY_CONVERT)

Comment: @userMT, I've just added the datatypes from that view. It appears that log date is the only datetime datatype. Everything else is nvarchar or nchar. As you mentioned, this error may be from the tables the view is referencing.

Comment: Still, the error might be coming from the conversion defined in the view:
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), LOGDATE, 101) + ' ' + LOGTIM AS DATETIME ) AS [Log Date]
Because LOGTIM is nvarchar and it can have an invalid time value.
You can test this by running a simple `select max([Log Date]) from dbo.vw_STARLIMS_PI` (no where condition). If you get the same error it is caused by the view.

Comment: If you don't get the error then it might be caused by one of these: `[Log Date] > ?`, where the binding value for the parameter ? is treated as nvarchar. 
Are you able to show us how this is called (the actual values of 4 parameters)?

If not, you can substitue each ? with `TRY_CAST(? as datetime)`. This would avoid the error by converting any non-convertible ? value to NULL. Obviously this may not be what you want but it would help with narrowing the source.

Comment: And I repeat my warning that your where condition appears to be incorrect: you should be very careful mixing ANDs and ORs like that without parenthesis.

Comment: @userMT, I actually ran the select statement you mentioned for testing. I got the same error. Would performing TRY_CONVERT on LOGTIM in the view code be a good step to try?

Comment: @userMT, I've addressed the where statement, but forgot to update it in this post. Used parenthesis to perform  LOG DATE > ? with every SAMPLE STATUS check.

Comment: Yes, if you are able to change the view, change CAST to TRY_CAST

Comment: If you want to see the log_date, Logtim values causing the error, run the SQL in the view, replacing SELECT... with SELECT LOGDATE, LOGTIM ... WHERE TRY_CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), LOGDATE, 101) + ' ' + LOGTIM AS DATETIME ) is null